# AngularJS $interval should dynamically in-/ decrease

Tags: angularjs, intervals

i just want to use $interval(anyFunction(){}, 1000); 
But value of 1000 should be variable, too.
If i change it by defining a variable, the interval won't change on the view.

Could someone post an example how to update the 'speed' of an $interval?

Thank you very much.

Just in case:

my controller:

```
$scope.food = 0;

var stop;
var farmInterval = 1000;

$scope.startFarming = function () {
    console.log('farming started...');
    if (angular.isDefined(stop)) return;

    stop = $interval(function () {
        $scope.food += 1;
    }, farmInterval); // <-- this value 'farmInterval' should be variable
}

$scope.stopFarming = function () {
    if (angular.isDefined(stop)) {
        $interval.cancel(stop);
        stop = undefined;
    }
}

$scope.increaseFarmInterval = function () {
    console.log(farmInterval);
    if (farmInterval > 100) {
        console.log('Increased by 50');
        farmInterval -= 50;
    } else {
        console.log('maximum reached.');
    }
}
```

my view:

```
<pre>{{food}}</pre>
<button class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="startFarming()">Farm</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="increaseFarmInterval()">Increase Farm Interval</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-click="stopFarming()">Stop</button>
```

Plunker-Version: http://plnkr.co/edit/V904pebWGvTWpyGMItwo?p=preview

Comment: Use [`$timeout`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout) instead.

Comment: You will need to write your own implementation with $timeout.

Comment: i somehow dont understand `increase by 50` when you are actually decreasing it.. and i really think it should work as it... can you setup a plunker showing the problem

Comment: I added a plunker version at the bottom of the first post.
I don't know why you mentioned $timeout. $timeout only fires once, i need to fire a function every x seconds. and I don't want to stop the interval. I just want to speed up the update of the automatical increasement of my 'food'. Could you show me a working example?

Comment: See the answer. It's related to `$timeout` as they said. For @HarishR: *increase* -even when what he's doing is actully *decreasing*- is referred not to the interval but to the frequency -which is the inverse of interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use $timeout:

```
$scope.food = 0;
var farmInterval = 1000;
var shouldStop = true;

$scope.startFarming = function () {
    console.log('farming started...');
    shouldStop = false;
    var loop = function () {
        if (!shouldStop) {
            $scope.food += 1;
            $timeout(loop, farmInterval);
            //defers another call to this function in a timeout
            //on each "iteration" like this -actually it's not
            //an interation- you can control what interval time to assign
        }
    };
}

$scope.stopFarming = function () {
    shouldStop = true;
}

$scope.increaseFarmInterval = function () {
    console.log(farmInterval);
    if (farmInterval > 100) {
        console.log('Increased by 50');
        farmInterval -= 50;
    } else {
        console.log('maximum reached.');
    }
}
```

Notice how I converted the $timer in a chain of $timeout calls. This is not only good practice to alter the interval, but also was the only way a script could implement `setInterval` when a browser implemented only `setTimeout` those days.

Most of the code is already yours, but I modified the `$timer`-related logic and don't use `$timer` anymore, so you must inject `$timeout` instead (or also - it depends if you're using `$timer` somewhere else in the controller, or not).

So the logic was changed: you don't kill a timer. Instead you prevent a new `$timeout` iteration occurs, since -if you look closely- each iteration is created explicitly after the loop's central logic.

Comment: ah yes, now i got it.
really clever :)

THank you so much!

Comment: Watch out: I don't know how will this impact on performance (honestly - I don't know. perhaps it will be a bit slower), so don't know if this is good to be abused. However, other alternatives regarding "dynamic frequency" are even less performant.

Comment: Maybe, i just about something like using $interval and just stopping and loading it again with a new time-interval, because this timeinterval should change about once an hour. Ill keep this solution as long i don't know a better one.
Thank you very much :)